# Is there a ring isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}[x] / \langle x^2,x^3 \rangle$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

What is the approoach that I need to take on this kind of problems ? Because I don't even know if it is or not an isomorphism between them.

I tried to find a surjective homomorphism that has the kernel $ \langle x^2,x^3 \rangle$ to use the isomorphism theorem but no succes.
Can someone give me an advice on this ?  Thank you !

Comment: This looks like a trick question, since  $ \langle x^2,x^3 \rangle$ is just $ \langle x^2 \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ring isomorphism between $A= \mathbb{R}[x] / \langle x^2,x^3 \rangle$ and $B= \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

This is due to the fact that $A$ has nilpotent elements (like the class of $x$) whereas $B$ does not.

Comment: Oh, it was that simple eh ?It seems right, thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. However, if you're looking for a vector space isomorphism, I think the one I showed you before should work

Comment: I will remember that , thank you !